Getting error on connecting kafka as a consumer: Kafka There is no leader for this topic-partition as we are in the middle of a leadership election
I am facing an issue in Kafka js consumer. I am getting below error when 1 out of 3 of my broker is down and after that I am starting my kafka consumer:
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2024-05-27T15:37:38.287Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Response Metadata(key: 3, version: 6)","broker":"x.x.x.x:9092","clientId":"MyConsumer","error":"There is no leader for this topic-partition as we are in the middle of a leadership election","correlationId":5,"size":48866}
I have set replication factor as 3 and min in sync replica as 2 for my all the topics and no topic is auto created.
I am expecting that the consumer should be able to connect the cluster.

wait till leader is elected for topic partition and then try to connect.

How to check when a leader is elected for topic partition. is there any event in kafka js?
